# Get Element from another XML file, based on an element value from current XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I use the following XSLT code to extract a list of elements from another XML file:

```
<xsl:variable name="titleCodes" select="document('other_XML.xml')/list"/>
```

The `other_XML.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="struktur_berufe.xsd">
    <job id="15339" bkz="B 01104-101">
        <type>t</type>
        <name>
            <name_nl>Job a</name_nl>
        </name>
    </job>
    <job>
        ...
    </job>
    ...
</list>
```

I now want to extract the `id` attribute of the `job` element, filtered by the `name_nl` element. The value by which I filter is from the XML file I am trying to transform, which looks like this:

```
<JobPost>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>
        Job a    <!-- value I filter by -->
    </title>
</JobPost>
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```
<TitleCode>
    <xsl:value-of select="$titleCodes/job[type='t']/name[name_nl=title]/ancestor::job/@id"/>
</TitleCode>
```

However, the problem seems to be, that `[name_nl=title]` is empty, since it looks for the`title` element in the `other_XML.xml`, which it of course doesn't have.

I also tried using a variable like this:

```
<TitleCode>
    <xsl:variable select="title" name="ab"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$titleCodes/job[type='t']/name[name_nl=$ab]/ancestor::job/@id"/>
</TitleCode>
```

But that still return `''`.

So is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your "other_XML.xml" is not well formed. You have an opening `<berufeliste >` tag, but a closing `<list>` tag. I am guessing you started translate the tags, but didn't quite complete it....

Comment: Oh yeah, that's my fault. I wanted to translate it quickly, so that the elements are not german. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are in a template matching `JobPost`, the expression you want is this....

```
<xsl:value-of select="$titleCodes/job[type='t']/name[name_nl = current()/title]/ancestor::job/@id"/>
```

So `current()/title` selects the `title` element for the current `JobPost` node, not the `name` node in the expression.

If this doesn't work, it is probably because you have whitespace in the `title` node in your XML, so try this...

```
 <xsl:value-of select="$titleCodes/job[type='t']/name[name_nl = normalize-space(current()/title)]/ancestor::job/@id"/>
```

It is probably the white space causing issues with your second attempt with the variable too.

Note that you could also write the expression like this, to remove the use of `ancestor` in the expression

```
<xsl:value-of select="$titleCodes/job[type='t'][name/name_nl = normalize-space(current()/title)]/@id" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The use of `current()` and `normalize-space()` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to read the `@id` within `<job>`, it should be enough to put all your filters in one predicate:

```
job[type='t' and name/name_nl=$ab]/@id
```

This way there's no need to navigate.